Isolated function app does not log traces but only information
I have a function app that only logs informational and higher. This is my Program.cs:
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();

        var contextualization = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IOptions<ExecutionContextOptions>>()?.Value;

        var config = new ConfigMan(contextualization.AppDirectory);
        services.AddSingleton(config);

        var devOpsRepo = new EDWRepo(config.Values.DB_EDW);
        services.AddSingleton<EDWRepo>(devOpsRepo);

    })
    .ConfigureLogging(logging => {
        logging.Services.Configure<LoggerFilterOptions>(options => {
            LoggerFilterRule defaltRule = options.Rules.FirstOrDefault(rule => rule.ProviderName == "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider");
            if (defaltRule is not null)
            {
                options.Rules.Remove(defaltRule);
            }
        });
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();

Host file:
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    "queues": {
      "messageEncoding": "none"
    }
  },
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      },
      "logLevel": {
        "default": "Trace"
      },
      "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
    },
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Trace",
      "Function": "Trace"
    }
  }
}

And function:
[Function(nameof(VesselAddOrUpdate))]
public async Task Run([QueueTrigger("update-or-add-vessel", Connection = "QueueConnection")] QueueMessage vesselJson)
{
    _logger.LogInformation($"FUNKTION HAS RUN INFO", Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DataContracts.SeverityLevel.Information);
    _logger.LogTrace($"FUNKTION HAS RUN TRACE", Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DataContracts.SeverityLevel.Information);
}

And in my AI i can only see information:

Function is running on .NET 8.0 Isolated mode. Any suggestions?


I have created Queue trigger with run time stack .NET 8.0 isolated function.
While running the function I have sent a queue message from storage queue got triggered and getting logs as expected. check below:

Program.cs:
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
        services.Configure<LoggerFilterOptions>(options =>
        {
            LoggerFilterRule toRemove = options.Rules.FirstOrDefault(rule => rule.ProviderName
                == "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider");

            if (toRemove is not null)
            {
                options.Rules.Remove(toRemove);
            }
        });
    })
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, config) =>
    {
        config.AddJsonFile("host.json", optional: true);
    })
    .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
    {
        logging.AddApplicationInsights(console =>
        {
            console.IncludeScopes = true;
        });

        logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();

Function1.cs:
 public class Function1
  {
      private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;

      public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger)
      {
          _logger = logger;
      }

      [Function(nameof(Function1))]
      public void Run([QueueTrigger("hello", Connection = "queueconn")] QueueMessage message)
      {
          _logger.LogInformation($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {message.MessageText}");
          _logger.LogTrace("this is trace log");
      }
  }

host.json:
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Trace"
    },
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"

      },
      "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
    }
  }
}

I have sent queue message like below:

Output:

